# How to plot a graph for the output of table() in R for Categorical variables against their occurring frequencies?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

```
library(gapminder)
a <- table(gapminder$continent)
a
#  Africa Americas     Asia   Europe  Oceania 
#     624      300      396      360       24
```

How do I plot a histogram in R for the below table where categorical should be in the X-axis and frequencies should be on the y-axis?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `plot` method for a table so you can simply do the following:

```
library(gapminder)
a <- table(gapminder$continent)
plot(a)
```

[image]

Or you could plot it as a barplot:

```
barplot(a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `a` in `as.data.frame` and then plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
a <- as.data.frame(table(gapminder$continent))
ggplot(a, aes(Var1, Freq)) + geom_col()
```

[image]